# Infinitesimals | limits question

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a question that I am not sure if I did well. can you give me your way to prove it?

Here is the question:

Suppose $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}{(a_n-b_n)}=l$, with $l\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}{(a_n)}=\infty$ . Does $b_n$ converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
b_n = (b_n - a_n) + (a_n) \to -l + \infty = \infty.
$$
So, no.

Comment: ok, thank you! that is what I thought.

Comment: @dfdf1 You're welcome. Feel free to accept an answer as you see fit.

Comment: BTW, can I ask u one last question? it's a similar question.

Comment: @dfdf1 yes you can ;)

Comment: thank you!!!
Suppose $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}{(a_n/b_n)}=l$, with $l\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}{(a_n)}=\infty$ . What can we say about $b_n$?

Comment: @dfdf1 I'd be happy to give you the answer, but I think you have to find this yourself and say us where you are stuck... For example, try to write $b_n = \frac{b_n}{a_n}a_n$. What can you say?

Comment: Ohhh I see! $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}{(b_n)}=\infty$
Next time I will write what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assume b_n converges to m.

Then

$\lim_{n} (a_n)=\lim_{n}((a_n-b_n)+b_n)=$

$\lim_{n}(a_n-b_n)+\lim_{n}(b_n)=l+m$,

a contradiction.

Note : If $\lim c_n, d_n$ exist then

$\lim (c_n+d_n)=\lim c_n +\lim d_n$.